# C input issue

Tags: c, gcc, struct, fgets

================================================================

```
typedef struct {
    union {
        struct {
            char fn[5];
            char ln[5];
        } fullname;
        char name[5+5+1];
    }
    unsigned int age;
    unsigned int area_code;
} my_struct;
```

The above is a struct that I have no control over. I personally am not a fan, but the struct is "legal".

================================================================

***My code:***

```
void caller {
    my_struct str;
    str = (my_struct){}; //initialise
    fill(&str);

    printf("%s [%s/%s]\n", str.name, str.fullname.fn, str.fullname.ln); // PROBLEM!
}

void fill(my_struct * str) {
    //first name
    printf("Enter first name: ");
    fgets(str.fullname.fn, sizeof(str.fullname.fn), stdin);
    if (str.fullname.fn[strlen(str.fullname.fn) - 1] == '\n')
        str.fullname.fn[strlen(str.fullname.fn) - 1] = '\0';

    //last name
    printf("Enter last name: ");
    fgets(str.fullname.ln, sizeof(str.fullname.fn), stdin);
    if (str.fullname.ln[strlen(str.fullname.ln) - 1] == '\n')
        str.fullname.ln[strlen(str.fullname.ln) - 1] = '\0';

    sprintf(str.name, "%s %s", str.fullname.fn, str.fullname.ln);

    printf("Age: ");
    scanf("%ud", &str.age);
    getchar();

    printf("Area Code: ");
    scanf("%ud", &str.area_code);
    getchar();
}
```

================================================================

If the input was:

- joe
- moe
- 18
- 214

The printout at `// PROBLEM` is:

```
joe moe [joe moe/oe]
```

instead of

```
joe moe [joe/moe]
```

Any ideas? I cannot, for the life of me, figure out why the values of fn and ln are changing...

Comment: I'm not new at C but by no means proficient, so feel free to call me stupid and show me obvious mistakes. FYI: the struct was not written by me and so I cannot change it.

Comment: He did not make it.And he is forced to use it.

Comment: @hexa: Like I said, it is not written by me and I cannot change it. I'm sorry you refuse to answer..

Comment: @hexa "The above is a struct that I have no control over. I personally am not a fan, but the struct is "legal"." Meh.

Comment: Oh I missed that part, sorry :(

Comment: I'm thinking first name is "joe m" and last name is "oe"

Comment: @Xaade: LOL if that were true, life would be easier and the program very messed up!

Comment: @Sagar I meant that the contents of those fields are that. I didn't mean that was the intent. It was a nudge in the right direction for debugging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `name` and `fullname` share the memory (because of the `union`). So

```
sprintf(str.name, "%s %s", str.fullname.fn, str.fullname.ln);
```

also writes over `fn` and `ln`.

Not a bad question, but I don't really see how to cleanly solve this. The way I'd do it: get rid of the `sprintf` above, and do it on your own.

```
void caller
{
    fill(&str);

    printf("%s %s [%s/%s]\n", str.fullname.fn, str.fullname.ln, str.fullname.fn, str.fullname.ln);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I just removed the sprintf. Now to sit and change other stuff to get around this.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is here:

```
 sprintf(str.name, "%s %s", str.fullname.fn, str.fullname.ln);
```

sprintf can't operate on overlapping memory regions.

What you can do is to NOT put a `\0` after the first name, but a space instead of the `\n` and just print `str.name`.

Also, initialize the array with `' '` (spaces) it would make inputs for the 1st name that are less than 5 chars.

```
memset(&str, ' ', sizeof(str));
```

Comment: Thanks! The ' ' instead of '\0' is a good idea. It will help join the two. I'm not sure what you mean for the memset though

Comment: imagine this, you fill the entire name array with spaces ok? But the guy first name is only 2 letters. But you have a max of 5 chars for the first name. If you don't fill in with spaces you will get garbage on the 3 remaining letters. Was I clear?

Answer (score 0):

The name part of the struct is a **union**, so it's either `name` or `fullname`, but not both at the same time. So after setting name the field fullname is invalid. The problem with unions is that you have to provide a mechanism for detecting which part of the union is actually used. I don't see anything here to decide whether name or fullname is used.